# Resolve u into components that are parallel and perpendicular to any other nonzero vector v.

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Resolve u (a vector) into components that are parallel and perpendicular to any other nonzero vector v.

Should I simply put $$ u = \langle u_1, \, u_2, \, u_3 \rangle \qquad v = \langle v_1, \, v_2, \, v_3 \rangle $$
$$ u \cdot v = 0 \qquad u \times v = 0$$
and solve it from there using the method of system of equations?

Comment: Are you saying that $u$ and $v$ are the same vector? If not, what do you mean by "the same goes for $v$"? And just what is the question in the box asking? The only vector that is parallel to every other vector is the zero vector, which is also the only vector that is perpendicular to every other vector. Do you mean that both $u$ and $v$ are given, and then we are to find the components of $u$ relative to $v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial remark: $kv$ is parallel to $v$ for any scalar $k$

Fewer trivial remark: Any vector parallel to $v$ is of the form $kv$. Therefore the component of $u$ parallel to $v$ will be of the form $kv$.

Another trivial remark: $u=(u-kv)+kv$.

Okay, with that framework, we can see what we need to do: $u$ is the sum of the perpendicular and parallel components, so we need to make $u-kv$ perpendicular to $v$.

What is the condition for this to occur? $(u-kv)\cdot v=0$. Hence by expanding the brackets,
$$ k = \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v}, $$
and we conclude that
$$u_{\perp} = u- \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v}v$$
is perpendicular to $v$,
$$u_{\parallel} = \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v}v$$
is parallel to $v$, and
$$ u_{\perp}+u_{\parallel} = u. $$

Comment: how do you get from (u - kv) . v = 0 to the next step. What is meant by expanding the brackets

Comment: The scalar product is distributive over addition, which means that $a \cdot (b+c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$. Hence $ 0=  (u-kv) \cdot v = u \cdot v - k v \cdot v $, which you can rearrange to get to my next equation.